# How to add info button to UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c

I need to add info button to toolbar.

can any one help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

You need to create a `UIButton` of type `UIButtonTypeInfoLight` (or, depending on your toolbar color `UIButtonTypeInfoDark`). You'd then use this button as the custom view for a `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton] autorelease];
myToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButtonItem, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the info image, then use `-initWithImage:style:target:action:`.

Comment: While I believe the original poster is simply not googling the answer and looking for an easy out, I really require help with this and did get to this post from google. This answer needs to provide more detailed instructions and thorough code examples.

Comment: It's better to use the predefined info button type, as the appearance of the standard info button might change with future OS releases.